# What should be the shape of an axisymmetric solar reflector that provides a uniform flux on the surface of a circular cylinder placed on its axis?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, geometry

I was wondering about creating a solar concentrator with an antisymmetric concave shape that is able to focus the collected light onto a circular cylinder positioned on the concentrator axis. The constraint would be to obtain a uniform flux on the cylinder.

A classical parabolic dish cannot provide such uniform flux as it is aimed at focusing the light into one point. Parabolic trough can illuminate cylinders but still not uniformly and require very large structures to obtain high fluxes.

Due to the axisymmetric shape of the concentrator, the solar flux per unit radius (azimuthally integrated solar flux) collected on the reflector increases linearly with the radius. As a result, the local slope of the reflector has to be chosen in order to distribute the flux uniformly over the collector, a right circular cylinder with constant section positioned on the axis.

[image: Illustration of the method used]

I already tried to obtain the equation describing the concentrator shape using the following assumptions :

- The power received at a given radius on an elemental surface $dr.rd\theta$ of the reflector is $F_R dr.rd\theta$, where $F_R$ is the solar power per unit area on the surface of the Earth
- The light bounces on a reflector element with local slope $\alpha(r)$
- Because of the deformation of the beam due to the reflection, the vertical "thickness" of the reflected beam is different from the elemental radial "thickness" of the original beam. The ratio between thicknesses can be easily determined using trigonometry as $dz=dr[\tan(\alpha)+\cot(2\alpha)]$
- This light beam then reaches the cylinder of radius $R$ and illuminates a surface $dz.Rd\theta$, thus, this elemental surface receives a power $F_C dz.Rd\theta$ where $F_C$ is the solar power per unit area on the surface of the collector.
- As the power reflected and collected must be the same, $F_R dr.rd\theta=F_C dz.Rd\theta=F_C[\tan(\alpha)+\cot(2\alpha)]dr.Rd\theta$
- This results in the equation $\tan(\alpha)+\cot(2\alpha) = \frac{F_R}{F_C} \frac{r}{R}$, with a solution $\alpha(r)=\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\left( \frac{F_C}{F_R} \frac{R}{r} \right)$
- As $\tan(\alpha(r))=\frac{dZ(r)}{dr}$, where $Z(r)$ is the curve describing the reflector, we have the ODE $\frac{dZ(r)}{dr}=\tan\left[\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\left( \frac{F_C}{F_R} \frac{R}{r} \right)\right]$
- Solving this ODE gives us
  $$Z(r) = Z_0 - \frac{1}{2} r^2 X \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{r^2 X^2} } + \frac{\ln \left[r \left(\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{r^2 X^2} } + 1\right)\right]}{2 X} + \frac{r^2 X}{2}$$
  where $X=\frac{F_R}{F_C}\frac{1}{R}$ and $Z_0$ is a constant that translates reflector's origin.

This equation is interesting, unfortunately it doesn't pass basic tests.

For example, we can enter a desired collector flux ($F_C=2000$ W/m²), a desired collector radius ($R=0.1$m), and use a standard value for solar irradiance at the surface of Earth ($F_R=1000$ W/m²), and plot the curve between $r_{min}=0.2$ and $r_{max}=0.3$. Using our equations with $Z_0=0.07$, the reflected beams should intersect the cylinder collector at minimum and maximum altitude of $z_{min}=0.01$ and $z_{max}=0.399$, respectively.

However, due to the conservation of the power over all the reflector and the collector, we should have
$$F_R \pi(r_{max}^2-r_{min}^2) = F_C 2 \pi R (z_{max}-z_{min}),$$
however, using our numbers we obtain
$$157\text{ W} \ll 488\text{ W}.$$

Do you see any flaws in my reasoning and do you have an idea on how I could obtain the right equation ?